# How do I set $ variables in unix?

Tags: unix, shell, csh

For example there is a long path that I `cd` to very often. How do I store the path in a variable so that I can use it everytime?

For example: I wan to be able to do this

```
cd $path
```

instead of

```
cd /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

everytime.

Comment: Are you using the "C Shell" (`csh`) or the more common Borne / Bash Shell (`sh` and `bash` respectively)?

Comment: @mctylr: C Shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming you really want csh/tcsh syntax (as you have tagged your question), put this

```
setenv P1 "/a/b/c/d/e/f"
```

to your .tcshrc

after that you are able to do

```
cd $P1
```

Answer (score 10):

In Bash shell:

`export FOO="/a/b/c"`

And you *don't* want to use $path. That's a special variable.

Comment: +1 good point about not using $path.  That would be bad.

Comment: Well, $PATH is a special variable, $path is not. I'd still avoid using it though.

Comment: You probably don't need export: just "foo=/a/b/c" would be enough, if you only need to refer to this variable in the current shell. If you want the variable propagated to child processes though (like when you run other programs from the shell), then you'd need the export command.

Comment: $path is fine, as mentioned above. And this question is tagged csh, and that syntax is for bash.

Answer (score 7):

It's not likely that you need your variable in the environment.

So, in csh instead of `setenv`, you can do:

```
set dir="/a/b/c/d/e/f"
cd $dir
```

or in Bash, instead of `export`:

```
dir="/a/b/c/d/e/f"
cd $dir
```

Comment: What are the differences between doing a `set dir="/a/b/c/d/e/f"` and `setenv dir "/a/b/c/d/e/f"`?

Comment: @Lazer: `setenv` exports variables so they are available in child processes. `set` sets variables that will only be used in the current environment (script or interactive shell). Most of the time, you only need to use `set`. Also, `set` supports arrays and `setenv` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Use export.

export your_path="/a/b/c/d/e/f"

cd $your_path

If you want it to persist through logins, you're going to need to edit it into your .profile file.

Comment: Or `~/.bash_profile` or, for system wide effect, `/etc/profile`. +1 for mentioning persisting it, in any case.

Comment: That is for the wrong shell. He wanted csh.

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to use `export`. In Bash or `sh`, `your_path="/a/b/c/d/e/f"` is almost always sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For csh you probably want to use **cdpath** . For bash, use **CDPATH** instead.

For example (bash):

```
prompt$ export CDPATH=:/a/b/c/d/e

prompt$ cd f
cd /a/b/c/d/e/f
```

You can also add more colon delimited directory targets. Keep the leading colon so CDPATH checks your current working directory first!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the path for one session, set the variable as usual

```
set long="/some/long/path/to/a/directory"
```

You can then `cd "$long"` as often as you like until the shell terminates or you set `long` again.

If you're interested in the variable being available to processes run from the shell session you should set it in your environment

```
setenv long "/some/long/path/to/a/directory"
```

If what you want is for the variable to be available to every session, instead of just the current one, you will need to set it in your shell run control.

```
$EDITOR ~/.cshrc
```

Then add  the `set` line or the `setenv` line shown above to automatically set the variable or environment variable for every session of csh.